# CS 1061 Ошибка после пересборки

Tags: c#, sql-server

До этого много раз пересобирал решение, но сразу после очередной пересборки выдало ошибку:

CS1061  "Uchet_KKT" не содержит определения "Uchet_KKT", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Uchet_KKT", принимающий тип "Uchet_KKT" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Uchet_KKT в этом случае является названием базы SQL.
Подскажите, что может быть причиной ошибки в этой ситуации?

Comment: Ну вам прямым текстом ведь пишут, что объект `Uchet_KKT` не содержит в себе `Uchet_KKT`... Где-то вы делаете `Uchet_KKT.Uchet_KKT`, либо без инициализации, либо в этом вашем `Uchet_KKT` вовсе отсутствует нужное. "В очередной раз" - просто так ничего не происходит, особенно не пропадают данные из класса и не пропадает их инициализация. Разбирайтесь с кодом и смотрите что вы трогали за последнее время. Больше, по этим крохам данных, сказать нечего.